# Does Fisher scoring always outperform Newton optimization?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, optimization, fisher-information

My understanding is that Fisher scoring has several advantages over Newton raphson optimization such as

1. Computational efficiency: if certain conditions are met (example:During MLE estimation, if link function is canonical+number of obs is sufficiently large, then expected Hessian is calculated without calculating second derivative rather it can be estimated by jacobian itself)
2. Better convergence (because Fisher information matrix is always positive definite. Also Fisher scoring is less affected by outliers)
3. Less impacted by the starting point chosen

Does this mean, Fisher scoring is always better than Newton Raphson optmization?
Are there any instances where Fisher fails/Newton Raphson performs faster/has better convergence?

Reference: 
[Mixed models: Theory and applications](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Mixed+Models%3A+Theory+and+Applications+with+R%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9781118091579), chapter 2, section 2.11